# Are Windows 10 Personalization settings available in Registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I'm working on a single .reg file that would combine all tweaks I usually manually do upon new Windows install - already found most of the things I want, but I cannot find anywhere the personalization settings available in Windows 10.

I would like to be able to tweak the taskbar (auto-hide, lock, etc), the lock screen ("get fun facts, tips.."=off) and the start menu ("occasionally show suggestions"=off).

Can I find those in Registry?

Comment: You question is too broad. You may find all tweaks in GitHub repo. Be specific about the tweaks.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, please check the 2nd paragraph of the question. I would like to tweak those checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction:

In Windows, new registry settings are made with [`RegSetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724922(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`RegSetValueEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx) (advanced). To capture those real-time operations, use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) application from Sysinternals. This application may be complex for first time user because it shows many operations so fast that it may hard to catch. But the procedure becomes easy by using filters.

#### Procedure:

1. Install Process Monitor (Procmon) > Run it > Accept the License Agreement > Quickly press **Ctrl + E** to stop the capturing process. Clear the Procmon window with **Ctrl + X**.
2. Open Process Monitor Filter Panel with **Ctrl + L**. Enter the conditions as following: **Operation -- is -- RegSetValue -- then Include**. Then click on Add button and OK.

[image: RegSetValue_Filter]

3. Now open the settings which you want to change (don't change it). Press **Ctrl + E** to start capturing and then enable/disable your settings quickly 2-4 times. You may see the changed registry in Procmon window. Quickly press **Ctrl + E** to stop capturing.

[image: Registry_Example.png]

Here is the registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Taskbar unlock(1) or lock(0)
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"TaskbarSizeMove"=dword:1

;Disable(1) or Enable(0) Lock screen suggested apps
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Cloud Content]
“DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures”=dword:1
```

#### Further reading:

1. [How-To Geek: Using Process Monitor to Troubleshoot and Find Registry Hacks](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/)
2. [Ask-Leo: How do I monitor what changes in my registry?](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_monitor_what_changes_in_my_registry.html)
3. [MSDN: Monitoring when registry keys are modified](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cobold/2011/11/29/monitoring-when-registry-keys-are-modified/)
4. [GitHub: CHEF-KOCH/regtweaks](https://github.com/CHEF-KOCH/regtweaks)